# Forward iterator with a moving end()

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

So, I'm designing a class which connects (over network) to a service to receive some data. I don't know how man data points I will be receiving in advance. Nevertheless I was wondering, if there is a way to make this class iterable using a forward_iterator in order to enjoy the STL in its full glory. My idea was something like:

```
self_type operator++() {
  // if there are some locally cached data points left return next
  // else connect to service again to receive the next batch of data
}
```

However, as I cannot provide a valid `end()`, I'm curious, if this is somehow still possible to do.

An alternative (and iterator-less) interface would probably look something like:

```
bool hasMoreDataPoints() const;
DataPoint& getNext();
```

which obviously won't work with any STL-algorithm.

Comment: Sounds like you need to implement your iterator like the streams do and the `end` is just a default constructed iterator.

Answer (score 4):

Do as the standard library do with `istream_iterator`: when you run out of data, set your iterator state such that it compares equal to a default-constructed object of that type. And then there's your `end()` equivalent.

Comment: Could you elaborate? So, I'd still inherit from std::iterator for instance and implement the interface in a straightforward manner, but just do the check for equality inside the `end()` function?

Comment: @NewProggie Don't inherit from `std::iterator`, it's a deprecated practice in C++17.

Comment: @KABoissonneault - but it's only 2016. <g> And if you're giving that advice, you need to explain what to do instead.

Comment: @NewProggie Look at how [`istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) is used and write your iterator the same way.

Comment: If you're interested in your iterators being compatible with the standard algorithms, then either provide the `typedef`s yourself directly your iterator class or specialize `std::iterator_traits`. You don't have to provide the ones you don't need

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there is some type of storage which you use in your class for caching, e.g. a `std::vector`. You can then just expose its `std::begin()` and `std::end()` iterators (in all the usual forms). Algorithms then directly work on the underlying container, and use the container-iterator's member functions like `operator++`, `operator==` and so on.

In case you need to introduce more logic, you need to create your custom iterator. Such can be basically done by composition, i.e. write a new class which contains an iterator corresponding to your storage container, and expose all functionality you need while adjusting it accordingly.

---

EDIT: as you said you use a list:

```
struct DataPoints
{
    std::list<double> _list; 
    auto begin() const
    {
        return _list.begin();
    }
    auto end() const
    {
        return _list.end();
    }
    //other versions: non-const begin and end, cbegin, cend
}
```

That's it already for the simple approach. You can use that just as a normal list:

```
DataPoints d;
std::find(d.begin(), d.end(), 10.0);
```

As said, if you need more logic, you probably need to write a custom iterator.

Comment: I'd probably use a std::list here as I want to avoid iterator invalidation when changing the underlying container. How would I adapt the implementation of std::lists iterator then?

Comment: It depends on what you want. If you simply want to loop over your DataPoints or apply standard library algorithms, the above is fine. If you need further logic in the inner-iterator components that extend the list-iterator functionality, the above is not sufficient. For example if you want your `operator++` to go randomly over the data. For such things, you need to write your own iterator.

Comment: By the way: there is no need to constrain the implementation to a forward iterator (as you state in the question title). In general, it should use the same iterator category as that of the underlying container.

Answer (score 0):

> *However, as I cannot provide a valid end(), I'm curious, if this is somehow still possible*....

You could use any of the container classes that comes with STL. 
Assume you are using a vector or a list or any other suitable container. Just use what's provided by STL and write your own wrapper

```
vector<datapoint> mydpvector;

//as data comes in
mydpvector.push_back(newdp);

vector<datapoint>::const_iterator cit=mydpvector.begin();
//now iterate everytime over the container

for(cit;cit!=mydpvector.end();cit++)
{
//get the data you need
}

//alternately if you need just the last element do this
mostrecentdp = mydpvector.back();
```